# error error Not Found (#404)

Tags: yii2

Intento consultar mi pagina con URLS limpias y me da un error Not Found (#404).
Le consulte con CHATGPT y me indico que me codigo esta bien y no hay errores de sintaxis

Tengo otro crud con la misma estructura apuntando a otras dos tabla y me funciona perfectamente
la vista que quiero rendedirizar esta aqui

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\piloto\views\clienteperfil
```

y la que me funciona esta aca.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\piloto\views\clientes
```

por favor ayudenme y feliz navidad para todos

```
    'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
```

Modal

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "cliente_perfil".
 *
 * @property int $idperfil
 * @property int $idEstatus
 * @property int $numero
 */
class ClientePerfil extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'cliente_perfil';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['idEstatus', 'numero'], 'required'],
            [['idEstatus', 'numero'], 'integer'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'idperfil' => 'Idperfil',
            'idEstatus' => 'Id Estatus',
            'numero' => 'Numero',
        ];
    }
}`
```

controller

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\ClientePerfil;
use app\models\ClientePerfilSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * ClientePerfilController implements the CRUD actions for ClientePerfil model.
 */
class ClientePerfilController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return array_merge(
            parent::behaviors(),
            [
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'delete' => ['POST'],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Lists all ClientePerfil models.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new ClientePerfilSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($this->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single ClientePerfil model.
     * @param int $idperfil Idperfil
     * @return string
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($idperfil)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($idperfil),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new ClientePerfil model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return string|\yii\web\Response
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new ClientePerfil();

        if ($this->request->isPost) {
            if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'idperfil' => $model->idperfil]);
            }
        } else {
            $model->loadDefaultValues();
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing ClientePerfil model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param int $idperfil Idperfil
     * @return string|\yii\web\Response
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($idperfil)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($idperfil);

        if ($this->request->isPost && $model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'idperfil' => $model->idperfil]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing ClientePerfil model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param int $idperfil Idperfil
     * @return \yii\web\Response
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($idperfil)
    {
        $this->findModel($idperfil)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the ClientePerfil model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param int $idperfil Idperfil
     * @return ClientePerfil the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($idperfil)
    {
        if (($model = ClientePerfil::findOne(['idperfil' => $idperfil])) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php

use app\models\ClientePerfil;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\grid\ActionColumn;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/** @var yii\web\View $this */
/** @var app\models\ClientePerfilSearch $searchModel */
/** @var yii\data\ActiveDataProvider $dataProvider */

$this->title = 'Cliente Perfils';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="cliente-perfil-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Cliente Perfil', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

   
`<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'idperfil',
            'idEstatus',
            'numero',
            [
                'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
                'urlCreator' => function ($action, ClientePerfil $model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return Url::toRoute([$action, 'idperfil' => $model->idperfil]);
                 }
            ],
        ],
 ]); ?>
`
</div>
```

La url: http://localhost/piloto/web/clienteperfil/index

lo hice intente con otro crud y funciona perfectamente.

```
'urlManager' => ['enablePrettyUrl' => true,'showScriptName' => false,'rules' => [],],
```

`

espero que se pueda renderizar mi crud

Comment: Si tu controlador es ClientePerfilController debes llamarlo de esta forma /cliente-perfil/    la url completa seria http://localhost/piloto/web/cliente-perfil/index